# wrong number of arguments(at least 1)

Tags: ruby, iterator

as part of training for a ruby challenge, I've been asked to create a method substrings(string), which will take a string, and return an array with all of it's substrings.

i.e

```
substrings("cat") #=> ["c", "ca", "cat", "a", "at", "t"]
```

To do this, I tried creating the following method, but when I run it, I get the error
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (at least 1)`

```
def substrings(string)
  i = 0 
  answer_arr = []

  while i < string.count 
    for val in i...string.count do 
      substring = string.(i..val)
      unless answer_arr.include?(substring)
        answer_arr << substring
      end
    end
    i+=1
  end
  answer_arr
end

substrings("stepan")
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def substrings(string)
  (0...string.length).flat_map { |i|
    (i...string.length).map {
      |j| string[i..j]
    }
  }
end
```

Example:

```
>> substrings('cat')
=> ["c", "ca", "cat", "a", "at", "t"]
```

Answer (score 4):

count was an incorrect method to use. it should have been length

```
def substrings(string)

    i = 0 
    answer_arr = []

    while i < string.length 
        for val in i...string.length do 
            substring = string[i..val]
            unless answer_arr.include?(substring)
                answer_arr << substring
            end
        end
        i+=1
    end

    answer_arr
end

substrings("stepan")
```

Answer (score 3):

Newer Ruby versions have [`Array#repeated_combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination):

```
str = 'cat'
(0...str.length).to_a.repeated_combination(2).map { |a, b| str[a..b] }
#=> ["c", "ca", "cat", "a", "at", "t"]
```

**Explanation:**

This solution is based on an array of sub string ranges:

```
                # 0 1 2 (indices)
ranges = [0..0, # c
          0..1, # c a
          0..2, # c a t
          1..1, #   a
          1..2, #   a t
          2..2] #     t
```

The above array can easily be built with `repeated_combination`:

```
ranges == [0,1,2].repeated_combination(2).map { |a, b| a..b }
#=> true
```

Comment: Can't figure out why constant value `2` in `repeated_combination`. Shouldn't this be `1-length.string`

Comment: These are sub string ranges, `2` because of *start* (`a`) and *end* (`b`)

Comment: @Bala added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
a="cats"
b = Array.new
a.chars.each.with_index { |i,j| b << a.chars.combination(j+1).to_a }
b.each{ |i| i.each { |j| puts j.join() } }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on your example?